# How could a pub/sub-like system be implemented in a functional language?

Tags: functional-programming, publish-subscribe

I am not looking for an actual implementation, but just an idea of what such a system would look like.

Comment: Approximately the same way you implement it in any other paradigm? You'll have streams of data, data structures that hold subscribers to that stream that you map over, functions that transform and combine streams of data, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Research 'Functional Reactive Programming' or FRP:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming

A common *flavour* of FRP is Reactive Extensions which has a number of implementations in various languages.  Although not the purist definition of FRP, it is possibly the most widely used functional framework for pub/sub.